# Finding the most coordinates as possible

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

I'm trying to solve a mathematic riddle,
I'm having B , Bands, and C Clubs.
each of the B bands has a coordinate(x,y) in km, and each club has also (x,y) coordinates.
I need to pair as much bands as I can to a each club, each band can perform in 1 club, and each club can have only 1 band.

band cant go to a location which is farther then 50km.

here is my idea:
I thought I should use Closest pair of points problem algorithm and then match each coordinate of a band(which is not taken) with another club which is closet and not taken also.

what do you think about it? or should I use other methods?

Comment: I think this should be moved to StackOverflow or CS Stack Exchange. Maybe some QAP theory is helpful, though.

Comment: @cronos2 thanks, well I thought of it  more like a theorical question ....

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem. Theory is largely discussed in those sites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greedy algorithm won't necessarily give you the best result. It's possible, for instance, that if you start by pairing the first few bands with the closest clubs, then a later band will be all out of adjacent clubs, but you could have given an early band a different club to leave room for the later band.

This problem is essentially a maximum matching problem in the bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $B \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} C$, where

- $B$ is the set of bands,
- $C$ is the set of clubs,
- $b \in B$ is adjacent to $c \in C$ if the distance between $b$ and $c$ is at most $50$ km.

The standard way to solve this is the Ford–Fulkerson method ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford-Fulkerson_algorithm)).

The idea is that we can increase a partial matching by finding augmenting paths: paths $(b_0, c_0, b_1, c_1, \dots, b_k, c_k)$ in $G$ such that $b_0$ and $c_k$ are unpaired, but $b_1$ is paired to $c_0$, $b_2$ to $c_1$, and in general $b_{i+1}$ to $c_i$. Then we can switch all these pairings to pairing $b_0$ with $c_0$, $b_1$ with $c_1$, and so on, up to $b_k$ with $c_k$. This gives us one more pair.

Augmenting paths can always be found unless you've reached the maximum matching, and one way to find them is by a breadth-first search.